# Image from iMac to MacBook Pro using Mini DisplayPort

Tags: linux, macbook, imac, mini-displayport

I have iMac 27 with non-working display and MacBook Pro Late 2008. Can I connect MacBook to iMac as monitor? Maybe it possible with Linux?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you simply need to get the data off the iMac, simply turn off the iMac, and use Target Disk Mode (press and hold T when booting) - and then you can treat the iMac like an external drive, and copy your files off it. Unless you are trying to achieve something different...?

Comment: I know of no sensible method to do this. But there are ways to do something similar if you just want to temporarily access the data.

Comment: I want use MacBook Pro as display for iMac. I want watch picture from iMac in my MacBook. That's all

Comment: Only iMacs support [Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592). Just get/rent/lend a DisplayPort display elsewhere. Or get the iMac fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any 2011 and later MAC (except for 27" 5K models) as monitor for another system
In order to do that you need to connect the Thunderbolt cable first and than boot the "monitor"-Mac while keeping the F2 key (or Fn-F2 depending on keyboard settings) pressed. This boots it in "monitor" mode.

For the Macbook 2008 this isn't possible.

Comment: I want use MacBook Pro as display for iMac. I know that did't work with OS X, but maybe it possible in Linux? Maybe I can install Linux on MacBook and use it as display?

Comment: @cmashinho No. the hardware doesn't allow it. The video-hardware must be able to turn the output connector into an input which isn't possible on the earlier models (or the recent 5K models).